# Python: Associativity of (**) not behaving as desired

Tags: python

I have this code:

```
from __future__ import print_function

a = lambda i=1: print('Line 1') or i if i else 1
b = lambda j=1: print('Line 2') or j if j else 2
c = lambda k=1: print('Line 3') or k if k else 3
d = lambda l=1: print('Line 4') or l if l else 4

q = a(True)**b(True)**c(True)**d(True)
```

The operator `**` is right associative. So as the parser/interpreter goes through the string given in `q`, it should call `d` and then `c` and then ... finally `a`. Right? Nope.

It prints: 
  Line 1
  Line 2
  Line 3
  Line 4

What started all this is that I thought I could come up with a really clever way to abuse operator associativity in order to print the string backwards while having them on the same consecutive lines, [following the instructions from this closed golf post](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/20654/execute-prints-backwards?rq=1)

Comment: It is right associative, i.e. `x**y**z == x**(y**z)`. What you don't know is that left side in `x**y` is always evaluated before the right side. Now, what is the question?

Comment: Oh! In the future, is there a document that shows these kinds of comparisons? I looked for it, but could not find a definitive source.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Python specifies that expressions are, in general, evaluated left-to-right.](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#evaluation-order)  So the operands of your sequence of `**` operators will be evaluated from left to right.

The language specification has this note in [the description of the power operator](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#the-power-operator):

> Thus, in an unparenthesized sequence of power and unary operators, the operators are evaluated from right to left (this does not constrain the evaluation order for the operands): `-1**2` results in `-1`.

Note the part about the evaluation order of the operands.  So Python evaluates `a ** b ** c` like this:

```
t1 = a
t2 = b
t3 = c
t4 = t2 ** t3
t5 = t1 ** t4
```

And `t5` is the value of the expression.

Comment: "Python doesn't specify the order in which it evaluates the operands of a binary operator" - [yes it does](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#evaluation-order). What it doesn't do is connect the precedence or associativity of an operator with evaluation order.

Comment: I couldn't find that in my Googling.  Thanks for the link.  I've revised my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Borrowing from [What is the associativity of Python's ** operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2383034/what-is-the-associativity-of-pythons-operator)

> In an unparenthesized sequence of power and unary operators, the
>   operators are evaluated from right to left (**this does not constrain
>   the evaluation order for the operands**).

Here is something that can do what you wanted to -

```
from __future__ import print_function

print_list = [
    lambda: print('Line 1') ,
    lambda: print('Line 2') ,
    lambda: print('Line 3') ,
    lambda: print('Line 4') ,
    ]

_ = [f() for f in print_list[::-1]]
```