# Why does the operation 2 ** 2 ** 2 ** 2 ** 2 ** 2 cause python to hang?

Tags: python, variables

```
var = 2 ** 2 ** 2 ** 2 ** 2 ** 2
```

I try this operation in Python 2.7.12 and Python 3.5.2.

Don't make any judges. Do it, and tell me why my Notebook Lenovo ideapad310 (i5-6k Series, 8 GB RAM) and ever other computer that I execute the same operation in Python just crashes (stop to answer / console dont't back).

OBS.: English, as you can see, is not my first language.

Comment: can you describe in details what you mean by "freaks out" ? Which python version do you use, on which system, and what is the error message ?

Comment: `2 ** (2 ** (2 ** (2 ** (2 ** 2))))` is a **huge** number: `2 ** (2 ** 65536)`, or in other words [powers are right associative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2383034/what-is-the-associativity-of-pythons-operator).

Comment: Wouldn't you freak out if you were asked to raise 2 to the power of a twenty thousand digit number?

Comment: The question itself is unclear. What did the OP get as result is not indicated, what the OP expected as result is not indicated.

Comment: @Faggiano you can "prevent this type of problem" by not asking your PC to calculate a number that large (significantly larger than the number of atoms in the Universe).

Perhaps what you wanted was `(((((2**2)**2)**2)**2)**2)`, which is pretty fast, but also something completely different.

Comment: Can you write the value you expect this to assign to your variable?

Comment: I just want to see the answer. My python don't come back from console.

Comment: It's too large for the memory of probably any computer. Thus, it won't show any output. https://repl.it/K788/0

Comment: That's it @Pac0 !!! You are close of what I want to mean! Don't you think that could be a bug? Or an implication of Python don't give a size to a Variable? How can I control this type of problems?

Comment: Well, don't try to compute such huge numbers in the first place ;) . Honestly, if your computation had multiple small steps, you could check for the memory usage. But with only one big computation like your one, I don't think you can do much, except use a script around the interpreter and check for python interpreter errors at this level.

Comment: the "no number limit" of python is by design. Maybe you need to change language. But why do you need to compute this beast ? What is your real problem  ?

Comment: anyway, your question has already been edited to remove the "How can I prevent it" part. Now it states clearly "Why this happens". For the "How can I prevent crash from this computation", it deserves a separate question. Be sure to be clear on what you want to achieve exactly.

Comment: Thank you @Pac0 for your Guidance! I get what I expected from your perspective.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The order of operations for powers occur right-to-left.  So

```
2 ** 2 ** 2           == 2 ** 4
2 ** 2 ** 2 ** 2      == 2 ** 16 
2 ** 2 ** 2 ** 2 ** 2 == 2 ** 65536
```

The last one is a really big number.  It has 19729 digit.  So appending one more `2` to this chain means you are taking

```
2 ** 2003529930406846464979072351560255750447825475569751419265016973710894059556311453089506130880933348101038234342
907263181822949382118812668869506364761547029165041871916351587966347219442930927982084309104855990570159318959639524863
372367203002916969592156108764948889254090805911457037675208500206671563702366126359747144807111774815880914135742720967
190151836282560618091458852699826141425030123391108273603843767876449043205960379124490905707560314035076162562476031863
793126484703743782954975613770981604614413308692118102485959152380195331030292162800160568670105651646750568038741529463
842244845292537361442533614373729088303794601274724958414864915930647252015155693922628180691650796381064132275307267143
998158508811292628901134237782705567421080070065283963322155077831214288551675554073345107213112427399562982719769150054
883905223804357045848197956393157853510018992000024141963706813559840464039472194016069517690156119726982337890017641517
190051133466306898140219383481435426387306539552969691388024158161859561100640362119796101859534802787167200122604642492
385111393400464351623867567078745259464670903886547743483217897012764455529409092021959585751622973333576159552394885297
579954028471943529913543763705986928913757153740001986394332464890052543106629669165243419174691389632476560289415199775
477703138064781342309596190960654591300890188887588084733625956065444888501447335706058817090162108499714529568344061979
690565469813631162053579369791403236328496233046421066136200220175787851857409162050489711781820400187282939943446186224
328009837323764931814789848119452713007440220765680910376203999203492023906626264491909167985461515778839060397720759279
378852241294301017458086862263369284725851403039615558564330385450688652213114813638408384778263790459607186876728509763
471271988890680478243230394718650525660978150729861141430305816927924971409161059417185352275887504477592218301158780701
975535722241400019548102005661773589781499532325208589753463547007786690406429016763808161740550405117670093673202804549
339027992491867306539931640720492238474815280619166900933805732120816350707634351669869625020969023162859350071874190579
161241536897514808261904847946571736601005892476655445840838334790544144817684255327207315586349347605137419779525190365
032198020108764738368682531025183377533908861426184800374008082238104076468878471647552945326947661700424461063311238021
134588694532200116564076327023074292426051582811070387018345324567635625951430032037432740780879056283663406965030844225
855967039271869461158513793386475699748568670079823960604393478850861649260304945061743412365828352144806726676841807083
754862211408236579802961200027441324438432402331257403545019352428776430880232850855886089962774458164680857875115807014
743763867976955049991643998284357290415378143438847303484261903388841494031366139854257635577105335580206622185577060082
551288893332226436281984838613239570676191409638533832374343758830859233722284644287996245605476932428998432652677378373
173288063210753211238680604674708428051166488709084770291208161104912555598322366244868556651402684641209694982590565519
216188104341226838996283071654868525536914850299539675503954938371853405900096187489473992880432496373165753803673586710
175783994818471798498246948060532081996066183434012476096639519778021441199752546704080608499344178256285092726523709898
651539462193004607364507926212975917698293892367015170992091531567814439791248475706237804600009918293321306880570046591
458387208088016887445835557926258465124763087148566313528934166117490617526671492672176128330845273936469244582892571388
877839056300482483799839692029222215486145902373478222682521639957440801727144146179559226175083889020074169926238300282
286249284182671243405751424188569994272331606998712986882771820617214453142574944015066139463169197629181506579745526236
191224848063890033669074365989226349564114665503062965960199720636202603521917776740668777463549375318899587866282125469
797102065747232721372918144666659421872003474508942830911535189271114287108376159222380276605327823351661555149369375778
466670145717971901227117812780450240026384758788339396817962950690798817121690686929538248529830023476068454114178139110
648560236549754227497231007615131870024053910510913817843721791422528587432098524957878034683703337818421444017138688124
249984418618129271198533315382567321870421530631197748535214670955334626336610864667332292409879849256691109516143618601
548909740241913509623043612196128165950518666022030715613684732364660868905014263913906515063908199378852318365059897299
125404479443425166774299659811849233151555272883274028352688442408752811283289980625912673699546247341543333500147231430
612750390307397135252069338173843322950701049061867539433130784798015655130384758155685236218010419650255596181934986315
913233036096461905990236112681196023441843363334594927631946101716652913823717182394299216272538461776065694542297877071
383198817036964588689811863210976900355735884624464835706291453052757101278872027965364479724025405448132748391794128826
423835171949197209797145936887537198729130831738033911016128547415377377715951728084111627597186384924222802373441925469
991983672192131287035585307966942713416391033882754318613643490100943197409047331014476299861725424423355612237435715825
933382804986243892498222780715951762757847109475119033482241412025182688713728193104253478196128440176479531505057110722
974314569915223451643121848657575786528197564843508958384722923534559464521215831657751471298708225909292655638836651120
681943836904116252668710044560243704200663709001941185557160472044643696932850060046928140507119069261393993902735534545
567470314903886022024639948260501762431969305640666366626090207048887438898907498152865444381862917382901051820869936382
661868303915273264581286782806601337500096593364625146091723180312930347877421234679118454791311109897794648216922505629
399956793483801699157439700537542134485874586856047286751065423341893839099110586465595113646061055156838541217459801807
133163612573079611168343863767667307354583494789788316330129240800836356825939157113130978030516441716682518346573675934
198084958947940983292500086389778563494693212473426103062713745077286156922596628573857905533240641849018451328284632709
269753830867308409142247659474439973348130810986399417379789657010687026734161967196591599588537834822988270125605842365
589539690306474965584147981310997157542043256395776070485100881578291408250777738559790129129407309462785944505859412273
194812753225152324801503466519048228961406646890305102510916237770448486230229488966711380555607956620732449373374027836
767300203011615227008921843515652121379215748206859356920790214502277133099987729459596952817044582181956080965811702798
062669891205061560742325686842271306295009864421853470810407128917646906550836129916694778023822502789667843489199409657
361704586786242554006942516693979292624714524945408858422726153755260071904336329196375777502176005195800693847635789586
878489536872122898557806826518192703632099480155874455575175312736471421295536494084385586615208012115079075068553344489
258693283859653013272046970694571546959353658571788894862333292465202735853188533370948455403336565356988172582528918056
635488363743793348411845580168331827676834646291995605513470039147876808640322629616641560667508153710646723108461964247
537490553744805318226002710216400980584497526023035640038083472053149941172965736785066421400842696497103241919182121213
206939769143923368374709228267738708132236680086924703491586840991153098315412063566123187504305467536983230827966457417
620806593177265685841681837966106144963432544111706941700222657817358351259821080769101961052229263879745049019254311900
620561906577452416191913187533984049343976823310298465893318373015809592522829206820862230332585280119266496314441316442
773003237792274712330696417149945532261035475145631290668854345426869788447742981777493710117614651624183616680254815296
335308490849943006763654806102940094693750609845588558043970485914449584445079978497045583550685408745163316464118083123
079704389849190506587586425810738422420591191941674182490452700288263983057950057341711487031187142834184499153456702915
280104485145176055306971441761368582384102787659324662689978418319620312262421177391477208004883578333569204533935953254
564897028558589735505751235129536540502842081022785248776603574246366673148680279486052445782673626230852978265057114624
846595914210278122788941448163994973881884622768244851622051817076722169863265701654316919742651230041757329904473537672
536845792754365412826553581858046840069367718605020070547247548400805530424951854495267247261347318174742180078574693465
447136036975884118029408039616746946288540679172138601225419503819704538417268006398820656328792839582708510919958839448
297775647152026132871089526163417707151642899487953564854553553148754978134009964854498635824847690590033116961303766127
923464323129706628411307427046202032013368350385425360313636763575212604707425311209233402837482949453104727418969287275
572027615272268283376741393425652653283068469997597097750005560889932685025049212884068274139881631540456490350775871680
074055685724021758685439053228133770707415830756269628316955687424060527726485853050611356384851965918968649596335568216
975437621430778665934730450164822432964891270709898076676625671517269062058815549666382573829274182082278960684488222983
394816670984039024283514306813767253460126007269262969468672750794346190439996618979611928750519442356402644303271737341
591281496056168353988188569484045342311424613559925272330064881627466723523751234311893442118885085079358163848994487544
756331689213869675574302737953785262542329024881047181939037220666894702204258836895840939998453560948869946833852579675
161882159410981624918741813364726965123980677561947912557957446471427868624053750576104204267149366084980238274680575982
591331006919941904651906531171908926077949119217946407355129633864523035673345588033313197080365457184791550432654899559
705862888286866606618021882248602144999973122164138170653480175510438406624412822803616648904257377640956326482825258407
669045608439490325290526337532316509087681336614242398309530806549661879381949120033919489494065132398816642080088395554
942237096734840072642705701165089075196155370186264797456381187856175457113400473810762763014953309735174180655479112660
938034311378532532883533352024934365979129341284854970946826329075830193072665337782559314331110963848053940859283988907
796210479847919686876539987477095912788727475874439806779824968278272200926449944559380414608770641941810440758269805688
038949654616587983904660587645341810289907194293021774519976104495043196841503455514044820928933378657363052830619990077
748726922998608279053171691876578860908941817057993404890218441559791092676862796597583952483926734883634745651687016166
240642424241228961118010615682342539392180052483454723779219911228595914191877491793823340010078128326506710281781396029
120914720100947878752551263372884222353869490067927664511634758101193875319657242121476038284774774571704578610417385747
911301908583877890152334343013005282797038580359815182929600305682612091950943737325454171056383887047528950563961029843
641360935641632589408137981511693338619797339821670761004607980096016024823096943043806956620123213650140549586250615282
588033022908385812478469315720323233601899469437647726721879376826431828382603564520699468630216048874528424363593558622
333506235945002890558581611275341783750455936126130852640828051213873177490200249552738734585956405160830583053770732533
971552620444705429573538361113677523169972740292941674204423248113875075631319078272188864053374694213842169928862940479
635305150560788126366206497231257579019598873041195626227343728900516561111094111745277965482790471250581999077498063821
559376885546498822938985408291325129076478386322494781016753491693489288104203015610283386143827378160946341335383578340
765314321417150655877547820252454780657301342277470616744241968952613164274104695474621483756288299771804186785084546965
619150908695874251184435837306590951460980451247409411373899927822492983367796011015387096129749705566301637307202750734
759922943792393824427421186158236161317886392553095117188421298508307238259729144142251579403883011359083331651858234967
221259621812507058113759495525022747274674369887131926670769299199084467161228738858457584622726573330753735572823951616
964175198675012681745429323738294143824814377139861906716657572945807804820559511881687188075212971832636442155336787751
274766940790117057509819575084563565217389544179875074523854455200133572033332379895074393905312918212255259833790909463
630202185353848854825062897715616963860712382771725621313460549401770413581731931763370136332252819127547191443450920711
848838366818174263342949611870091503049165339464763717766439120798347494627397822171502090670190302469762151278521956142
070806461631373236517853976292092025500288962012970141379640038055734949269073535145961208674796547733692958773628635660
143767964038430796864138563447801328261284589184898528048048844180821639423974014362903481665458114454366460032490618763
039502356402044530748210241366895196644221339200757479128683805175150634662569391937740283512075666260829890491877287833
852178522792045771846965855278790447562192663992008409302075673925363735628390829817577902153202106409617373283598494066
652141198183810884515459772895164572131897797907491941013148368544639616904607030107596818933741217575988165127000761262
789169510406315857637534787420070222051070891257612361658026806815858499852631465878086616800733264676830206391697203064
894405628195406190685242003053463156621891327309069687353181641094514288036605995220248248886711554429104721929134248346
438705368508648749099178812670565665387191049721820042371492740164460943459845392536706132210616533085662021188968234005
752675486101476993688738209584552211571923479686888160853631615862880150395949418529489227074410828207169303387818084936
204018255222271010985653444817207470756019245915599431072949578197878590578940052540122867517142511184356437184053563024
181225473266093302710397968091064939272722683035410467632591355279683837705019855234621222858410557119921731717969804339
317707750755627056047831779844447637560254637033369247114220815519973691371975163241302748712199863404548248524570118553
342675264715978310731245663429805221455494156252724028915333354349341217862037007260315279870771872491234494477147909520
734761385425485311552773301030342476835865496093722324007154518129732692081058424090557725645803681462234493189708138897
143299831347617799679712453782310703739151473878692119187566700319321281896803322696594459286210607438827416919465162267
632540665070881071030394178860564893769816734159025925194611823642945652669372203155504700213598846292758012527715422016
629954863130324912311029627923723899766416803497141226527931907636326136814145516376656559839788489381733082668779901962
886932296597379951931621187215455287394170243669885593888793316744533363119541518404088283815193421234122820030950313341
050704760159987985472529190665222479319715440331794836837373220821885773341623856441380700541913530245943913502554531886
454796252260251762928374330465102361057583514550739443339610216229675461415781127197001738611494279501411253280621254775
810512972088465263158094806633687670147310733540717710876615935856814098212967730759197382973441445256688770855324570888
958320993823432102718224114763732791357568615421252849657903335093152776925505845644010552192644505312073756287744998163
646332835816140330175813967359427327690448920361880386754955751806890058532927201493923500525845146706982628548257883267
398735220457228239290207144822219885587102896991935873074277815159757620764023951243860202032596596250212578349957710085
626386118233813318509014686577064010676278617583772772895892746039403930337271873850536912957126715066896688493880885142
943609962012966759079225082275313812849851526902931700263136328942095797577959327635531162066753488651317323872438748063
513314512644889967589828812925480076425186586490241111127301357197181381602583178506932244007998656635371544088454866393
181708395735780799059730839094881804060935959190907473960904410150516321749681412100765719177483767355751000733616922386
537429079457803200042337452807566153042929014495780629634138383551783599764708851349004856973697965238695845994595592090
709058956891451141412684505462117945026611750166928260250950770778211950432617383223562437601776799362796099368975191394
965033358507155418436456852616674243688920371037495328425927131610537834980740739158633817967658425258036737206469351248
652238481341663808061505704829059890696451936440018597120425723007316410009916987524260377362177763430621616744884930810
929901009517974541564251204822086714586849255132444266777127863728211331536224301091824391243380214046242223349153559516
890816288487989988273630445372432174280215755777967021666317047969728172483392841015642274507271779269399929740308072770
395013581545142494049026536105825409373114653104943382484379718606937214444600826798002471229489405761853892203425608302
697052876621377373594394224114707074072902725461307358541745691419446487624357682397065703184168467540733466346293673983
620004041400714054277632480132742202685393698869787607009590048684650626771363070979821006557285101306601010780633743344
773073478653881742681230743766066643312775356466578603715192922768440458273283243808212841218776132042460464900801054731
426749260826922155637405486241717031027919996942645620955619816454547662045022411449404749349832206807191352767986747813
458203859570413466177937228534940031631599544093684089572533438702986717829770373332806801764639502090023941931499115009
105276821119510999063166150311585582835582607179410052528583611369961303442790173811787412061288182062023263849861515656
451230047792967563618345768105043341769543067538041113928553792529241347339481050532025708728186307291158911335942014761
872664291564036371927602306283840650425441742335464549987055318726887926424102147363698625463747159744354943443899730051
742525110877357886390946812096673428152585919924857640488055071329814299359911463239919113959926752576359007446572810191
805841807342227734721397723218231771716916400108826112549093361186780575722391018186168549108500885272274374212086524852
372456248697662245384819298671129452945515497030585919307198497105414181636968976131126744027009648667545934567059936995
464500558921628047976365686133316563907395703272034389175415267500915011198856872708848195531676931681272892143031376818
016445477367518353497857924276463354162433601125960252109501612264110346083465648235597934274056868849224458745493776752
120324703803035491157544831295275891939893680876327685438769557694881422844311998595700727521393176837831770339130423060
958999137314684569010422095161967070506420256733873446115655276175992727151877660010238944760539789516945708802728736225
121076224091810066700883474737605156285533943565843756271241244457651663064085939507947550920463932245202535463634444791
755661725962187199279186575490857852950012840229035061514937310107009446151011613712423761426722541732055959202782129325
725947146417224977321316381845326555279604270541871496236585252458648933254145062642337885651464670604298564781968461593
663288954299780722542264790400616019751975007460545150060291806638271497016110987951336633771378434416194053121445291855
180136575558667615019373029691932076120009255065081583275508499340768797252369987023567931026804136745718956641431852679
054717169962990363015545645090044802789055701968328313630718997699153166679208958768572290600915472919636381673596673959
975710326015571920237348580521128117458610065152598883843114511894880552129145775699146577530041384717124577965048175856
395072895337539755822087777506072339445587895905719156736
```

Comment: Also, Python supports arbitrarily large numbers, which means that, even though it's ludicrous, it will _try_ to perform the requested computation and store it in memory. There is no memory in the world to begin to hold the result, so the interpreter will probably crash after hogging your memory for a while.

Comment: Great answer! You give the best answer. But I just wondering why compiler/interpreter just crash.

Comment: @Faggiano : The above comment of jdehesa explains it : Python will **try** to compute it, but will fail because **it won't have enough memory** .

Comment: Yes!!! That's it @Pac0 !!! You are close of what I want to mean! Don't you think that could be a bug? Or an implication of Python don't give a size to a Variable? How can I control this type of problems?